Markov Chains - Application of Strong Markov Property (Gambler's Ruin)
There is this example (1.4.3, pg 21) from the book Markov Chains by James Norris. I have a very small question in one of its steps (I have also added some steps for clarity). Thanks in advance!
Background: The Gambler's Ruin problem. Let $\{X_n : n \geq 0\}$ be a Markov chain satisfying $P_{0,0} = 1$ (0 is an absorbing state), $P_{i,i+1} = p$ and $P_{i,i-1} = q$, with $p + q = 1$, for any $i \geq 1$.
Example: We want to obtain the complete distribution of the time to hit 0 starting from 1 in terms of its probability generating function. Set
$$H_j = \inf \{n \geq 0 : X_n = j\}$$
and, for $ 0 \leq s < 1 $,
$$\phi(s) = \mathbf{E}_1(s^{H_0}) = \sum_{n < \infty} s^n \mathbf{P}_1(H_0 = n).$$
Suppose we start at 2. Apply the strong Markov property at  $H_1$ to see that under $ \mathbf{P}_2 $, conditional on $H_1 < \infty$, we have $ H_0 = H_1 + \widetilde{H}_0 $, where $\widetilde{H}_0 $, the time taken after $H_1$ to get to 0, is independent of $ H_1 $ and has the (unconditioned) distribution of $H_1$. So,
$$\mathbf{E}_2(s^{H_0}) = \mathbf{E}_2(s^{H_1} \mid H_1 < \infty)\mathbf{E}_2(s^{\widetilde{H}_0} \mid H_1 < \infty)\mathbf{P}_2(H_1 < \infty)$$
$$= \mathbf{E}_2(s^{H_1} 1_{H_1 < \infty})\mathbf{E}_2(s^{\widetilde{H}_0} \mid H_1)$$
$$= \mathbf{E}_2(s^{H_1})\mathbf{E}_2(s^{\widetilde{H}_0} \mid H_1 < \infty)$$
$$= \mathbf{E}_2(s^{H_1})\mathbf{E}_1(s^{\widetilde{H}_0} )$$
$$= \mathbf{E}_2(s^{H_1})^2 = \phi(s)^2.$$
Then, by the Markov property at time 1, conditional on $ X_1 = 2 $, we have $H_0 = 1 + \widetilde{H}_0 $, where $\widetilde{H}_0$, the time taken after time 1 to get to 0, has the same distribution as $H_0$ does under $\mathbf{P}_2 $. So,
$$\phi(s) = \mathbf{E}_1(s^{H_0}) = p \mathbf{E}_1(s^{H_0} \mid X_1 = 2) + q \mathbf{E}_1(s^{H_0} \mid X_1 = 0)$$
$$= p \mathbf{E}_1(s^{1 + \widetilde{H}_0} \mid X_1 = 2) + q \mathbf{E}_1(s \mid X_1 = 0)$$
$$= ps \mathbf{E}_2(s^{H_0}) + qs$$
$$= ps \phi(s) + qs.$$
My question:
How is $\mathbf{E}_1(s^{\widetilde{H}_0}) = \mathbf{E}_2(s^{H_1})$ ?
